# thumbnail zoom on hover effect while cropping to original thumbnail's resolution

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been looking for a css or javascript/jquery solution to make an effect where you hover over a thumbnail and the thumbnail zooms in, but doesn't resize past the original image's bounds. For an example visit the site http://venablesbell.com/ and hover over any of the thumbnails below (they zoom out on hover, but i want to zoom in).

I was thinking about placing all thumbs each in their own iframe and writing a simple bit of css that changes the thumbnail's width/height equally on hover, but I was wondering if there's a better solution.

Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: And by "zoom in", I think that is "zoom out".

Comment: the site i'm referencing for the example they zoom out, and I'm looking to zoom in. the effect is similar though in that the image's bounding box isn't resizing when the image is resizing - it's as if the thumbnail image is always getting cropped to it's original resolution no matter what kind of resizing is going on. does that make sense? thanks